# Could someone give a concrete example of an amalgamation from model theory?

Tags: logic, model-theory

The theorem I have in mind can be found in page 135 of this book:

https://books.google.com/books?id=S6QYeuo4p1EC&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=Amalgamation+model+theory&source=bl&ots=wBxs9-czg0&sig=ONvsFiQNB1sDkwoE2XlCyVoMII8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EsrSVNHaJcyN7AbGpoDADg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=Amalgamation%20model%20theory&f=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to think of an example? Pick your favorite theory that's easy to understand, pick two models and a tuple from each satisfying the same type, and I bet you can amalgamate them.

Here's an example:

Let $V$ and $W$ be $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, with bases $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\{w_1,\dots,w_m\}$. Then $(v_1,v_2)$ have the same type in $V$ as $(w_1,w_2)$ in $W$, and indeed we can find a vector space $S$ with basis $\{s_1,\dots,s_{m+n-2}\}$ and embeddings $V\to S$ and $W\to S$ defined by $v_1\mapsto s_1$, $v_2\mapsto s_2$, $v_i\mapsto s_i$ for $i<2$, and $w_1\mapsto s_1$, $w_2\mapsto s_2$, and $w_i \mapsto s_{n+i-2}$ for $i>2$. These maps identity $(v_1,v_2)$ with $(w_1,w_2)$ as desired, and they're elementary embeddings by quantifier elimination.